# Multiple tables in ountputcache attribute sqldependency mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache, sqldependency

I am using outputcache sqldependency and it works absolutely fine, but now I want to depend on multiple tables.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, SqlDependency = "db:table1")]
```

My question: Is sqldependency support relying on multiple tables? if yes, then what is the syntax?

I tried the following syntax, but it did not work, it considers this `table1,table2` as a name for one table.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, SqlDependency = "db:table1,table2")]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
SqlDependency = "[database]:[table1];[database]:[table2]"
```

Comment: @Piotr Czarnecki, Hi, I have tried the same thing what you have explained. For first table change it works perfectly but for table2 its not working properly.  It access the action after 5 to 6 times to page refresh.

Comment: @Piotr Czarnecki, I have found the issue its due to the "pollTime" in webConfig. I have reduce the values so its works fine